# eclipse Installation at shared environment

Tags: eclipse

I want to have all the developers have a single eclipse installation, so I installed eclipse at the shared location.
Whenever I have tried to run the eclipse, I see that the installation is updated and actually another user can't run eclipse due to the permission issues.

The updated directory is 
.../eclipse/configuration

Can I somehow redirect this directory to the user specific location?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What OS are you using? How did you install Eclipse? And most importantly: _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: 1. It is Redhat linux
2. Don't exactly know. Sorry. I will recheck with the guy, who did real installation, if it is important.
3. Our developers need eclipse with a number of plugings. It should have Oracle WL plugin, clearcase plug in, C/C++ plugin etc... Apart from that different eclipse versions have to be used for the different versions of our product (Mars does not supports low JDK, for example). So I want to make life of our developers easy.

Comment: Download and extract a zip

Comment: Have you tried the new Eclipse Mars installer instead of downloading a zip? Did not try it myself, but I think this will install Eclipse in a "shared" folder (like `/usr` or so). Or, just install all your "required" plugins into Eclipse, re-zip it, and distribute that zip to your developers.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k. Probably will take the second approach